# Conditional normality implies marginal normality or bivariate normality?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions, marginal-probability

Let X and Y be two random variables.

If we know that both Y|X and X|Y are normal, then can we conclude that
(1) X and Y are normal respectively;
(2) X and Y are bivariate normal?

Thanks!

Edited:
The motivation behind this question is that
If the random vector [X Y]' follows a bivariate normal distribution,
then I think we know that X, Y, X|Y, and Y|X are all normal.

So my question is whether X|Y and Y|X being normal also implies that [X Y]' is bivariate normal.

Comment: Questions are usually much better received here if you provide evidence of what you have attempted.

Comment: Not sure this is helpful but I just wanna verify my understanding: When you say $Y|X$ is normal, do you mean $\forall x, Y|X=x$ is normal, i.e. $Y$ (when conditioned on $X=x$) has a cdf that is normal, with mean & variance possibly being functions of $x$?  If so, and further if you allow a "trivial" normal r.v. with variance 0, then (1) & (2) are false.  E.g. $X=Y$ then both $X|Y=y \sim N(y,0)$ and $Y|X=x \sim N(x,0)$, but clearly $X=Y$ can be anything you want.  (If you require non-zero variance then my argument doesn't apply.)

Comment: Request to "unlock" the question...?  IMHO it's interesting and OP's edits have shown the motivation behind it.  It lacks a "practical" context but is a valid theoretical question about the converse to a well known theoretical result.

Comment: @antkam: Isn't the claim obvious at least for continuous bivariate distributions?

Comment: @user21820 - Not sure what you mean...  The OP pre-conditions are that $X\mid Y$ and $Y \mid X$ are normal.  Can you conclude from these that $(X,Y)$ are bivariate normal?

Comment: @antkam: Somehow I did not get notified by your comment. I am not sure what I was thinking when I made the first comment, and cannot prove what I said...